# Translating SVG elements for an Isometric view

Tags: javascript, 3d, svg, raphael

I'm working on some JavaScript code to render standard 2D SVG/Canvas elements (drawn with [Raphael-JS](http://raphaeljs.com/)) in an isometric *3Dish* view.

Say we have two rectangles drawn next to each other. I then have them redrawn at the correct angles (basically a 30 degree twist) for an isometric view.

[image]

(*In the image above I've shown the origin for two corresponding elements.*)

My problem is I don't know how to properly translate all the individual elements so they "tile" correctly instead of just overlapping.

While actually using tiles would make things easier as I could just base any given tile's placement on the one before it, tiles won't work in this case. Everything is dynamic and will be more complex than simple x/y planes.

[Here is an image of some isometric tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKvmC.jpg) if there's any confusions as to how I want these objects to be placed.

Comment: Your title seems to indicate that you're using the HTML canvas element. Since Raphael uses SVG (even though they're talking about canvas over there as well) you might want to clear this up to get some answers. Interesting question, though!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, polarblau. I'll try to clarify my question.

Comment: Note that the graphic you have supplied in your question is not a correct isometric projection, assuming that the two squares are at the same height-from-ground. As shown in the url you supplied, the edges of adjacent tiles should remain aligned after projection. If you were attempting to show your problem, then you should perhaps make it more clear that this is the current/wrong result you are showing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't apply the transformation to the individual elements, but to the source elements as a collection. In Raphael, you could use something like

```
var s = paper.set();
s.push(square1, square2);
```

and now do the transformations without too much math, which is supposed to work like this:

```
// s.clone(); // if you want to keep originals
s.rotate(45, 0, 0).scale(1, .7).translate(100, 0);
```

(However, scaling of rotated items seems to be broken in RaphaelJS.)

Plain SVG example:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="-200,-500 1000,1000">
    <title>Isometric</title>
       <g id="source"> <!-- group -->
           <circle cx="-50" cy="-50" r="50"/>
           <rect width="100" height="100"/>
           <rect width="100" height="100" x="101"/>
           <rect width="100" height="100" x="50" y="-200"/>
       </g>
       <!-- make copy of group and apply transformations -->
       <use xlink:href="#source" transform="translate(500) scale(1, .7) rotate(-45)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Pumbaa80. Unfortunately this solution doesn't seem right for me. What I'd like is to eventually be able to input some coordinates of, say, a basic floor-plan. Then render then those coordinates in an isometric projection and extrude z-axis(height) from the element's "base". Later, via JavaScript, I want to be able to manipulate the individual elements: moving, deleting, adding and altering them. I can't really, draw z-axises (make cubes from the footprints) and then rotate the set. I suppose it *might* be possible to rotate everything and then extrude -continued->

Comment: <-continuted- heights by remeasuring the coordinates of each element. Doing so might work but seems pretty ugly problematically. Then again, maybe it is simpler that way. I'll try it out.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else, here is my Raphael-JS Google Groups posting on the scaling of rotated elements issue: http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/217a5edb9db22419

Comment: @j33r Pumbaa80 is correct, you should not be applying the transform to each element, but to the entire view.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Raphel.js 2.0](http://raphaeljs.com/) you can do this using the .transform() method and providing a transform string that rotates 45 degrees and scales vertically 70% (or whatever pitch you want). It's important to pay attention to the position you are rotating and scaling around as well - in this case I'm using 0,0. You will also notice I'm translating 100 over to the right to compensate for the rotation.

Transform strings are also great for this use case because you can simply prepend the projection transformation to the transformation of other objects in the scene and they will all end up in the right place.

For example (see http://jsfiddle.net/k22yG/):

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 320, 240),
    set = paper.set();

// Build a set to make it easier to transform them all at once
set.push(
    // Grid of rectangles
    paper.rect(0, 0, 50, 50),
    paper.rect(60, 0, 50, 50),
    paper.rect(0, 60, 50, 50),
    paper.rect(60, 60, 50, 50)
);

// Rotate, then scale, then move (describe in "reverse" order)
set.transform('t100,0s1,0.7,0,0r45,0,0');​
```